# How to install Grub Customizer?

Tags: boot, grub2

Entering command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

And the last lines read:

```
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So how can I safely customize booth sequence in the GNU-GRUB, Want Windows first and Ubunto second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like that particular PPA does not yet have support for Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic).

So you can either wait until the PPA supports Kinetic, or take the chance and modify the Repo to use 22.04 (Jammy) and hope it works.

Since the Grub version (and all dependency versions) are the same between Jammy and Kinetic, I'd say there is a good chance the Jammy version works on Kinetic.